# How can I download the starter branch version of code

Tags: android, kotlin, github

I want to download the starter branch but when I download it I find the main branch code even though I download it from the starter
https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-words-app/tree/starter

Comment: I have never used GitHub before, I thought I'm gonna go to the link and click on the green "code" button and click download ZIP that's all.

Comment: change the download url : https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-words-app/archive/refs/heads/starter.zip

Comment: Oh now it's working thank you, could you tell me how to do that? Maybe I'll need that for other projects.

Comment: copy the download url and edit the last part `https://github.com/.../.../[branch-name].zip` - going forward it would be beneficial to learn some source control (git) and command line basics as it will be helpful (if you don't already know git).

Comment: Ah for sure I will learn git I wanted to lean it after learning some android basics but I guess I need to learn git before that. Anyway thanks

Comment: it is beneficial, but climb one hill at a time. Focus on Android basics first - start small.